# How do you create a C program that resembles the nl command in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I am working on a project to create a C program that acts just like the nl command in Linux, with the exceptions; it only accepts limited options, does not accept dashes to denote standard input, and no need for division of documents into logical pages with headers/footers.

This is a link to an nl manual page: https://ss64.com/bash/nl.html

This is where I am at. The errors I have and cannot for the life of me fix, are as follows:

> ```
> Line 46: warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_line'; did you mean 'fgetline'? (-Wimplicit-function-declaration)"
> Line 46: warning: assignment to 'char *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast (-Wint-conversion)"
> Line 73: error: conflicting types for 'get_line'"
> Line 46: note: previous implicit declaration of 'get_line' was here."
> note: expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'char'"
> ```

The code I have currently:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

//Preprocessor constants:
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 100

//Prototypes:
int process_stream(FILE *fpntr);
char *fgetline(FILE *fpntr);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char filename;
    char *first_line;
    FILE *fpntr;

    int c;
    int lineNumber = 1;
    int beginningNum = 1;

    //Check for proper number of arguments:
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: firstline FILE\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //Get source and destination from arguments:
    filename = argv[1];

    //Open file for reading:
    fpntr = fopen(filename, "r");

    //Left out of body to below block:
    fprintf (stderr, "Error opening file %s: %s\n",
    filename, strerror(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if ((fpntr = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    //Get first line from file:
    if ((first_line = get_line(fpntr)) == NULL) {
        perror("Error reading line");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    // Print out line:
    printf("First line in file %s: \n%s", filename, 
    first_line);

    //read contents from file
    while ((c = fgetc(fpntr)) != EOF){
        if (beginningNum){
            printf("%d   ", lineNumber);
            beginningNum = 0;
        }

        if (c == '\n'){
            lineNumber++;
            beginningNum = 1;
        }
            printf("%c", c);
    }

    fclose(fpntr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
/*Function to get next line from open file and place it as 
  a legal string into
  a line buffer that is created locally and is static so it 
  can be returned.
  Returns pointer to line buffer, or else NIL on error or 
  immediate EOF.*/
char *get_line(FILE *fpntr)
{
  static char line_buff[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

  //Get first line from file and return
  if (fgets(line_buff, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fpntr) != NULL)
  return line_buff;
  else
  return NULL;
}
 
//EOF
```

Comment: You declare `fgetline()`; you call and define `get_line()`.  Make your mind up — the compiler can't do that for you.  The error message did a pretty good job of telling you what is probably wrong.  The other messages are corollaries of the first message.

Comment: Tip: Declare your functions before they're used, as in move `get_line` above `main`. If you get your preamble done first and then use them later there's less of a chance of messing things up by referencing the wrong name like you appear to have done here.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you fix that you have a massive *undefined behaviour* problem where you're returning a pointer to a temporary variable `line_buff`. It's not clear what that wrapper function does that's useful given how right now it's broken and may only work if the wind is blowing a very specific direction. It's often better to put the `fgets` code in your main parsing function so it's clear what's going on, and so you have complete control. This wrapper function just gets in the way.

Comment: There's other problems, too, like trying to jam a `char*` `argv` value into `char filename` which is going to get you one letter at best, and more likely a compiler error.

Comment: This may be unconventional or informal, but you all are amazingly fast! I am very  new to coding—especially in C—and I am working very hard to understand the complexities of coding in general.

Comment: @tadman: The `line_buff` variable I see is a `static char line_buff[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];` which is not a temporary (local, automatic) variable.

Comment: Can I make "char filename" an array to fix the issue @tadman ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, didn't see the sneaky `static`, but that's kind of a crummy way to do it anyway. As an industry we dug ourselves a deep hole writing completely thread-hostile functions like that. Like using two-digit years we should sort of strive to avoid that.

Comment: @Cthulhu: you need `char *filename` (a pointer) — or you can simply avoid the `filename` variable and use `argv[1]` where you pass `filename` to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken this to the shop and hammered it into functional shape:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: firstline FILE\n");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // argv[n] is type char*
    char* filename = argv[1];

    FILE* fpntr = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (!fpntr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error opening file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((fpntr = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    static char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    if (!fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fpntr)) {
        perror("Error reading line");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("First line in file %s: \n%s", filename, line);

    // Try and declare variables as close as possible to where they're used
    // as it makes figuring out what they are way easier. Types are very
    // important in C!
    int begin = 1;
    size_t lineNumber = 0;
    int c;

    // Note: Would be better to read line by line here instead of individual
    //       characters, fgets has you covered, but this is your call.
    while ((c = fgetc(fpntr)) != EOF){
        if (begin) {
            // You can get printf() to do the formatting for you if you
            // let it with %-4 being 4 wide (%4), left-aligned(%-4)
            // %zu is just the type used by size_t for display
            printf("%-4zu ", lineNumber);
            begin = 0;
        }

        if (c == '\n') {
            lineNumber++;
            begin = 1;
        }

        putc(c, stdout);
    }

    fclose(fpntr);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It Works on My Machine™ (Clang) and apart from needing to rewind (`fseek`) after your debugging code to dump the first line, it looks good.

On the whole it only took a few little nudges to get things to fit into place properly. You had the right idea, but a lot of the details were just a tiny bit off.

Unfortunately in C a single character can be the difference between "works fine" and agonizing hours of debugging or a whole slew of compiler errors.

Comment: Hello, I thank you much for helping me understand better. I do have a question. I noticed the program does not start counting, say "testfile3" (which is just a file containing random text) from the first line in the textfile3. Instead, it starts numbering on the second line of the file. I have attempted to fix this, but failed epically. Also, how can I have the while loop only number the lines containing text and skip blank lines in the test file? Again, have made several attempts at this, but my coding skill are still low-level.

Comment: I added a comment about needing to rewind the file with `fseek` if you do any test reads from the file first. As for blank lines, you'll need to run a quick test on each line before incrementing the counter and printing. This can be done with a simple `switch` statement that has `case ' '` and `case '\t'` branches, for example, both of which go to an "ignore" `break` clause.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't fully understand that the first time I read it, thank you again!

Comment: Each open file has a position pointer, effectively, that moves around when you do reads or writes. `ftell` will "tell" you what that position is, and `fseek` can move it to wherever you want relative to the beginning or end of the file.